# Adding, editing, and deleting data in jqgrid that gets reflected in the database using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, jqgrid

As with other questions, Oleg's assistance with jqgrid-related queries are very much helpful and appreciated. Through his answers I have been able to inch towards my goal; though what's bothering me is the editurl property. On most demos it's just someurl.php.

Oleg also said that this php file contains the instructions(mysql) to edit the database using data sent to it by jqgrid. By using Firebug I've seen that it is indeed posting the data entered but it results to Error 404 all the time. I've tried placing the someurl.php everywhere in the CI folder. And given that, I'm still not sure what to write in the someurl.php.

Can anyone please help? I've been stuck on implementing Add, Edit, and Delete the whole day.

Comment: The someurl.php is the php script which edit/remove the data in your sql. You have to put the correct url of this script in the editUrl option.

Comment: What url is that in CodeIgniter? Is it also relative to index.php? What folder does it go to?

Comment: The easiest way to see if it is relative to index.php is opening the console and look at the network events. You will see where is jqgrid looking for the needed script.

Comment: I've seen the network events and the path ended at index.php. Does that mean it searched up to there or stopped upon seeing it? It's weird because my someurl.php is alongside index.php. Though it's a blank php file, will it still result to error 404?

Comment: You have to look for the network event corresponding to the 'someurl.php'. Then you'll see the path which is used.
You can just put an `echo 'it works!'` in your someurl.php file to see if you have your 404 error.

Comment: Ooooh thank you very much. I've traced it successfully now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion of Ballantine, I finally solved this.

It turns out that someurl.php is indeed relative to index.php and is thus found at the controllers folder via CodeIgniter.

From there, it's just a matter of using someurl.php as a controller:

Here I took advantage of using the POST sent from the view page that contains jqGrid. They are the oper, clientCode, clientName, and id in my case.

Furthermore, on the query part, I could've used something like $this->db->update via CodeIgniter but I since I'm a beginner at mySQL, I might as well try to familiarize myself with the syntax.

And from here on, you could continue nesting this for the add and delete cases. I hope this helps someone!

```
else if($_POST["oper"] == 'edit'){


        $newCode = $_POST["clientCode"];
        $newName = $_POST["clientName"];
        $id = $_POST["id"];



        $this->db->query("UPDATE tblclient SET clientCode = '$newCode', clientName = '$newName' WHERE clientCode = '$id' LIMIT 1");

    }
```